# Access denied to mysql database

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1044

I created a database named `auth` yesterday in mysql.

Today, I went to access it by `USE auth;` but I got this output

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'auth'
```

I never used to have this problem when I created and used databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to database with root

```
mysql -u root -pyourpassword
```

(change yourpassword with password you have for root or leave in blank in case you havent set it). Now you should have access to your db. Check this thread how to set permissions for users [MySQL Add User Guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html).

Answer (score 0):

maybe try creating and using a new database to see if the problem is repeatable, or if it's specific to that database.